# Wordpress - How to adding a custom comment_type?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I want to add a custom comment type to some of the comments, but I don't know how to write the custom comment type with the comment form into the comment_type row in the database-table. I've tried it the following way, but it won't work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment_type" value="reader" id="comment_type" />
```

I've tried many hours and searched the whole web. :-/

Any suggestions?

Comment: do i interpret your approach correct? you want to check if a comment was posted by a reader of your blog or by an adminuser (most commonly yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

back again, now on a better keyboard than my phone ;-)

as you can see in the [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_type), `comment_type` is not an attribute you can set with a value you wish. it describes the *system* type of the command (either a trackback, pingback or simply, a comment)

considering my comment above, i guess you'd like to differ between your own comments and those of your visitors.

i solved this in my own blog theme by reacting on the author id of the comments.

following a snippet from my comments.php file:

```
$isCommentFromAuthor = get_the_author_id() == $comment->user_id;
// ...
<div class="<? if($isCommentFromAuthor) : ?>author-content<? else: ?>content<? endif ?>">
```

this solution checks the author of the current article and compares it with the comments author.
if the comment is from the articles author, another css class is passed to the comment container which will style it differently.

does this help you any further?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<input type="hidden" name="comment_type" value="reader" id="comment_type" />` in `comment_form`, you only need to hook [`preprocess_comment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment)

```
function preprocess_comment_handler( $commentdata ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['comment_type'] ) ) {
        $commentdata['comment_type'] = $_POST['comment_type'];
    }
    return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'preprocess_comment_handler' );
```